# Add file from different folder to git repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a git repository where i push most of my stuff.
Problem is that when i push from the folder (in Visual studio code git bash), it pushes all the files from that folder.
How can i make it so it also pushes all the files or only specific files from different directory to the git repo also?
**So i imagine it like this:**
I push normally like always: `git push -u origin main`
And all of the main folder files (That are already getting pushed) get pushed
And all of the other folder files/or only some in specific get pushed

The main folder has basics like server files etc (node.js to be exact).
And the other folders have the client files.

Comment: Are those files inside the repo?

Comment: No they are not, how can i add them?

Comment: I'm also curious, do you understand the concept of commits, why "pushes files" isn't quite true, and how to add/commit new files?

Comment: I do understand that but i just don't know how to add/commit a file from folder on my PC

Comment: Put them inside the folder which contains the `.git` folder. This is the root of the repo. Then you can add and commit them from bash. If this is not possible, you can use multiple repos.

Comment: You might consider creating your Git repo at a higher level in your directory structure. The Git repo has to contain all the files it's going to include.

Comment: Solved it by creating another local repository in that folder that i will push from, not the optimal solution i was looking for but good enough.